# How to make editable table cell

Tags: swift, uitableview

I'm looking for a way to make `UITableView` editable like in phone app in iOS when I want to edit the contact data, user should view data and shall be able to press on edit in order to edit the data.

I've been searching for a way to do this for weeks on the web, but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 1):

There are two methods that I use for editing table cells. The first method is tableView(_: canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath:). In this method you specify the section and row of the table view that can be edited. For instance>

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {

            if (indexPath.row == 0)||(indexPath.row == 2) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

In this example you specify that only the first and third row of the first section of the table can be edited.

The second method I use is the method tableView(_: didSelectRowAtIndexPath:). In this method you specify how to react when the user selects the cell (row). In this method you can specify anything you like to change the cell. You can for instance segue to another view and do whatever you want to do. I, however, usually use an alert or action sheet to change the cell. Here is an example that extends the previous example:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    //First check whether the right cell is being selected.

    let selectedIndexPath = self.trackDetailsTable.indexPathForSelectedRow

    //If the selected row is not in the first section the method returns without doing anything.
    guard selectedIndexPath?.section == 0 else {
        return
    }

    if selectedIndexPath?.row == 0 {
        //The first row is selected and here the user can change the string in an alert sheet.
        let firstRowEditAction = UIAlertController(title: "Edit Title", message: "Please edit the title", preferredStyle: .Alert)
        firstRowEditAction.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({ (newTitle) -> Void in

            newTitle.text = theOldTitle //Here you put the old string in the alert text field 
        })

        //The cancel action will do nothing.
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .Cancel, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })

        //The Okay action will change the title that is typed in.
        let okayAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

            yourObject.thatNeedsTheNewString = (firstRowEditAction.textFields?.first?.text)!
            //Do some other stuff that you want to do
            self.trackDetailsTable.reloadData() //Don’t forget to reload the table view to update the table content
            self.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
        })

        trackTitleEditAction.addAction(okayAction)
        trackTitleEditAction.addAction(cancelAction)
        self.presentViewController(trackTitleEditAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    if selectedIndexPath?.row == 2 {
        //The third row is selected and needs to be changed in predefined content using a standard selection action sheet.
        let trackLevelAction = UIAlertController(title: "Select Predefined Content”, message: "Please, select the content”, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.ActionSheet)

        for content in arrayOfPredefinedContent {
            predefinedContentAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: content, style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in

                yourObject.thatNeedsTheNewContent = content
                //Do some other stuff that you want to do
                self.trackDetailsTable.reloadData() //Don’t forget to reload the table view to update the table content
            }))

        }
        trackLevelAction.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (UIAlertAction) -> Void in


        }))

        presentViewController(trackLevelAction, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It's a general question but here's a general answer - you link your table cell with a segue to a new scene where you can display an editable form to the user.  The user clicks the table cell which triggers the segue.  You might find this Apple [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH2-SW1) useful.